# Calculate the limit: $\lim_{x \to1} \frac{1}{|x^2-1|}$

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

Calculate the limit
$$
\lim_{x \to1} \frac{1}{|x^2-1|} 
$$
Could you please tell me how to know if 1/0 is positive or minus infinity?

Comment: The key is to check the sign of the function near the value being approached.  In this case, $\frac 1{|x^2 - 1|} > 0$ both for $x$-values greater than $1$ and for those less than $1$.

Comment: Take two one-sided limits.

Answer (score 2):

For $ x \ne 1$, $\frac{1}{|x^2-1|}>0$, hence $\lim_{x \to1} \frac{1}{|x^2-1|}= + \infty$

Answer (score 2):

If you know the form is $1/0$ then all you have to ask yourself is: Is the quantity in the faction positive or negative; in this specific case, since there is an absolute value, it is clearly never negative.  However, the general approach would look like the following:

**Case 1:** $x>1$ (but very close to 1).  In this case $x^2 > 1$ so $x^2-1>0$ and the fraction is positive.  This shows you that

$$\lim_{x\to 1^{+}}\frac{1}{|x^2 - 1|} = +\infty$$

**Case 2:** $x<1$ (but very close to 1).  In this case $x^2 < 1$ so $x^2-1<0$.  However, in your case there is an absolute value, and so the denominator is positive.  This shows that

$$\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}\frac{1}{|x^2-1|} = +\infty$$

And you are done.  Note that in general, this is the approach you want to look at (look at both one-sided limits).